# Convert elements in masked astropy Table to np.nan

Tags: python, astropy

Consider the simple process of reading a data file with some non-valid entries. This is my `test.dat` file:

```
16        1035.22  1041.09    24.54     0.30     1.39     0.30     1.80     0.30     2.26     0.30     1.14     0.30     0.28     0.30   0.2884
127        824.57  1105.52    25.02     0.29     0.87     0.29     1.30     0.29     2.12     0.29     0.66     0.29     0.10     0.29   0.2986
182       1015.83   904.93    INDEF     0.28     1.80     0.28     1.64     0.28     2.38     0.28     1.04     0.28     0.06     0.28   0.3271
185       1019.15  1155.09    24.31     0.28     1.40     0.28     1.78     0.28     2.10     0.28     0.87     0.28     0.35     0.28   0.3290
192       1024.80  1045.57    24.27     0.27     1.24     0.27     2.01     0.27     2.40     0.27     0.90     0.27     0.09     0.27   0.3328
197       1035.99   876.04    24.10     0.27     1.23     0.27     1.52     0.27     2.59     0.27     0.45     0.27     0.25     0.27   0.3357
198       1110.80  1087.97    24.53     0.27     1.49     0.27     1.71     0.27     2.33     0.27     0.22     0.27     0.00     0.27   0.3362
1103      1168.39  1065.97    24.35     0.27     1.28     0.27     1.29     0.27     2.68     0.27     0.43     0.27     0.26     0.27   0.3388
```

And this is the code to read it, and replace the "bad" values (`INDEF`) with a float (`99.999`)

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import ascii

data = ascii.read("test.dat", fill_values=[('INDEF', '0')])
data = data.filled(99.999)
```

This works just fine, but if I instead try to replace the bad values with a `np.nan` (i.e., I use the line `data = data.filled(np.nan)`) I get:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

why is this and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted the issue is that the numpy `MaskedArray.filled()` method seems to try converting the fill value to the appropriate type before checking if there is actually anything to fill.  Since the table in the example has an `int` column, this fails within numpy (and astropy.Table is just calling the `filled()` method on each column).

This should work:

```
In [44]: def fill_cols(tbl, fill=np.nan, kind='f'):
    ...:     """
    ...:     In-place fill of ``tbl`` columns which have dtype ``kind``
    ...:     with ``fill`` value.
    ...:     """
    ...:     for col in tbl.itercols():
    ...:         if col.dtype.kind == kind:
    ...:             col[...] = col.filled(fill)
    ...: 

In [45]: t = simple_table(masked=True)

In [46]: t
Out[46]: 
<Table masked=True length=3>
  a      b     c  
int64 float64 str1
----- ------- ----
   --     1.0    c
    2     2.0   --
    3      --    e

In [47]: fill_cols(t)

In [48]: t
Out[48]: 
<Table masked=True length=3>
  a      b     c  
int64 float64 str1
----- ------- ----
   --     1.0    c
    2     2.0   --
    3     nan    e
```

Comment: Why is it only filling one masked element in your example and not all of them?

Comment: it can't fill the other columns with nan because one is an integer type and one is a string.

Comment: More directly, the function specifically takes an option for which dtypes to fill. kind='f' means fill columns where the dtype 'kind' is float.

Comment: Thanks. It could be made more general using `if col.dtype.kind in kind:` and pass `kind` as a list of dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's primarily a numpy problem, as it works with individual columns:

```
>>> data['col4'].filled(np.nan)
<Column name='col4' dtype='float64' length=8>
24.54
25.02
  nan
24.31
24.27
24.1
24.53
24.35
```

but you still can't construct a `Table` from this -

```
Table([data[n].filled(np.nan) for n in data.colnames])
```

raises the same error in `np.ma.core`.
You can explicitly set

```
data['col4'] = data['col4'].filled(np.nan)
```

but this apparently lets the table lose its `.filled()` method...
I am not that familiar with masked arrays and tables, but as you've already  filed a [related issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/7307) on Github, you might want to add this problem.

Comment: If you go straight to the numpy.ma.filled docs, using the example code, and try to fill with np.nan the same exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening fairly deep in numpy, in numpy.ma.filled. fill values have to be scalars, basically.

A messy solution that fills with nan's and still returns a table could look like:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import ascii
from astropy.table import Table

def fill_with_nan(t):
    arr = t.as_array()
    arr_list = arr.tolist()
    arr = np.array(arr_list)
    arr[np.equal(arr, None)] = np.nan
    arr = np.array(arr.tolist())
    return Table(arr)


data = ascii.read("test.dat", fill_values=[('INDEF', '0')])
data = fill_with_nan(data)
```

Comment: Its unfortunate that one must resort to such a convoluted way to do such a simple operation. Thank you Brian.

Comment: I think my solution below is a bit more straightforward, and definitely much faster since it doesn't convert everything back to Python lists.

Comment: Yes, I think your solution is better than my hack. It's both more general and leaves the table as a masked table.

Answer (score -1):

Cut out the middleman? `fill_values=[('INDEF', np.nan)])` seems to work.

Comment: The `'0'` is there for a reason sadly http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/read.html#f1

Comment: also, it doesn't actually seem to fill with nans. This was the first thing I tried too.